# Trying to use this.wdioRetries, but always get it's equal to 0

Tags: mocha.js, appium, webdriver-io

my code snip:
(test should fail and start a retry)

```
let utils = require("../utils/utils");
const { default: newFlowScreen } = require("../../pageobjects/flow/general/createFlowScreen");
const { default: mainMenuScreen } = require("../../pageobjects/general/mainMenuScreen");
const { testData } = require("../../../testData");
const commonActions = require("../process/commonActions");

describe("Retry trial test", () => {
    it("Login to application", async function() {
             console.log('Retry count:', this.wdioRetries);
             await commonActions.loginToApplication(testData.retryTrialTest.user, testData.retryTrialTest.pass);
    });

    it("Enter the project", async function () {
             await expect(await mainMenuScreen.getProject(testData.retryTrialTest.projectName)).toExist({
            message: `Project name ${testData.retryTrialTest.projectName} not found.`,
         });
        await commonActions.enterProject(testData.retryTrialTest.projectName);
            await commonActions.moveToQuestionnarieIfNeeded();
    });

    it("Empty Screen",async function () {
        // await commonActions.createButton();
        await newFlowScreen.clickOnStartFromBlank();
    });
});
```

**the code is failing and being retried in my console - but my console.log says that my Retry count: 0**

in my config:

```
  specFileRetries: 1,
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: "bdd",
    timeout: 600000,
    retries: 1,
    bail: false
  },
```

my webdriverIO version in my package.json is: "webdriverio": "^8.26.3"
what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!